# Countif greater than previous cell

Tags: excel, function, statistics, logic, countif

I want to count the number of times in a column that a cell value is equal to zero and the cell in the row under is greater than zero.

Let's say that my column is the one bellow.

```
Row 1: 5
Row 2: 2
Row 3: 0
Row 4: 4
Row 5: 3
Row 6: 0
Row 7: 5
Row 8: 0
Row 9: 2
```

Then the result of the formula should be 3 because of the 3 pairs:

```
Row 3: 0
Row 4: 4

Row 6: 0
Row 7: 5

Row 8: 0
Row 9: 2
```

I tried using countif or sumif but it seems to me that you can only input fixed reference cell.
Any idea how I could do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sumproduct will work here

First, we build up the range we need to compare (I'm going to assume you are using column A)

```
A1:A8<A2:A9
```

note the offset by one, so we miss the last value in the firstst array, and the first cell in the second.

Convert from `TRUE/FALSE` values to 0/1 to add up

```
--(A1:A8<A2:A9)
```

and wrap this with SUMPRODUCT to add the numbers up

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A8<A2:A9))
```

Note that you can use SUM instead of SUMPRODUCT, but you will have to remember to use an array formula with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> - The formula will then look like this: `{=SUM(--(A1:A8<A2:A9))}`

Comment: Thank you! I added the condition for the cell to be equal to zero and the final formula worked perfectly! `=SOMMEPROD(--(A1:A8<A2:A9);--(A1:A8=0))`

Comment: I have a similar problem and this works so far. However my range is dynamic, since the source is a power query. I found a way to define a dynamic range using Offset ( `=OFFSET(origin,0,0,COUNTA(range),COUNTA(range))` ) however I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this. Seems to me like this would be a more common issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 2007 or later:

=COUNTIFS(A1:A9,0,A2:A10,">0")

Regards